# How do I get a list of keys where the keys are found in some text?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and some text:

```
dogs = {"jack russell": "benny", 
        "labrador": " oscar",
        "golden retriever": "ol' yeller"}

some_text = ["I have a jack russell and a golden retriever. They are 2 and 4 years old.", "My neighbour has a 3 cats."]
```

The output I want is:

```
[['jack russell', 'golden retriever'], [None]]
```

What I've got so far is:

```
some_list = []

for x in dogs.keys():
    matched_dogs = []
    for y in some_text:
        if x in y:
            matched_dogs.append(x)
        else:
            matched_dogs.append(None)
    some_list.append(matched_dogs)         

print(some_list)
[['jack russell', None], [None, None], ['golden retriever', None]]
```

My script is not quite there but surely there's a simple answer. Any nudge in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how *this* data leads to *this* desired result?  That is, *why* your program should produce this output?

Comment: @ScottHunter I've got thousands of text samples where I need to identify words that are the keys of a dictionary. Essentially I'm doing a key word/phrase search on a bunch of text.

Comment: @delvins78 What determines that output format, though? Why are they 2-element lists, whose second element is always `None` ?

Comment: @ScottHunter I want to find all occurrences of my dictionary keys in a list of texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for y in some_text:
    matched_dogs = []
    for x in dogs.keys():
        if x in y:
            matched_dogs.append(x)
    if len(matched_dogs) == 0:
        matched_dogs.append(None)
    some_list.append(matched_dogs)
```

This is desired result?

Comment: `if len(matched_dogs) == 0:` can be summed to `if not matched_dogs:`

Comment: Thanks @PedroLobito

Answer (score 1):

This gives the desired output:

```
res = [[], []]
for key in dogs:
    for text in some_text:
        if key in text:
            res[0].append(key)
            break
    else:
        res[1].append(None)
```

Note that an `else` after a `for` will only be executed if the `for` ended naturally, not through a `break`.

Comment: I want to find all occurrences of my dictionary keys in a list of texts.

Comment: Got it, fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something a little more compact:

```
# Get OP's original result
some_list = [ [x for x in dogs.keys() if (x in y) ] for y in some_text]
# Fix the lines w/o any dogs
some_list = [z if z else [None] for z in some_list]
```

Comment: I also wrote an answer similar to it `[list(filter(lambda x: x in text,dogs)) for text in some_text]` but i think yours is more pythonic.

Comment: @ScottHunter very compact thanks. always find it useful to expand a list comprehension into for loops to make sure I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an iteration over the list and check for the existence of keys in the elements, append to list if so else a `None` if nothing is found:

```
dogs = {"jack russell": "benny", 
        "labrador": " oscar",
        "golden retriever": "ol' yeller"}

some_text = ["I have a jack russell and a golden retriever. They are 2 and 4 years old.", "My neighbour has a 3 cats."]

res = []
for x in some_text:
    lst = []
    for k in dogs:
        if k in x:
            lst.append(k)
    if not lst:
        lst.append(None)
    res.append(lst)

print(res)
```

The output is exactly what is desired:

```
[['jack russell', 'golden retriever'], [None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` here.

```
>>>ans=[list(filter(lambda x: x in text,dogs)) for text in some_text]
# [['jack russell', 'golden retriever'], []]
```

---

Now replace `[]` with `[None]`

```
ans=[lst if lst else [None] for lst in ans]
# [['jack russell', 'golden retriever'], [None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single line comprehension:

```
[x if len(x) > 0 else [None] for x in [[key for key in dogs if key in text]
                                       for text in some_text]]
```

With you data it gives as expected:

```
[['jack russell', 'golden retriever'], [None]]
```

Comment: `if len(x) > 0` can be replaced by `if x`

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but here's my 2c:

```
result = []
for text in some_text:
    temp = [k for k in dogs if k in text]
    if not temp:
        temp.append(None)
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
# [['jack russell', 'golden retriever'], [None]]
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/85c7496df9)